# PHP - glob() sort not working on Host's server

Tags: php, sorting, directory, glob

Although this code SORTS the filename and then SORTS the extension perfectly ***locally***, I cannot get this to work on any Hosting company's (shared) server - regardless of the PHP version.  It simply will not do any sorting on my Host's server.  I have tried this on many different hosting companies' servers.  So this is not an issue with one hosting company/server.  (*FYI:  The oldest version of PHP tested was 5.2.17 - most recent tested was 5.3.26.  Local = 5.3.5)

OUTPUT EXAMPLE:
a_first.jpg
a_first.png
a_first.zip
b_second.doc
b_second.gif
b_second.jpg

```
<?php

function getFileExt($filename) {
    return substr(strrchr($filename,'.'),1);
}

$handle=opendir(dirname(__FILE__));

while (($file = readdir($handle))!==false) {
    $fileExt = strtolower(getFileExt($file));
    if(in_array($file, $ignore_file_list)) { continue; }
    if(in_array($fileExt, $ignore_ext_list)) { continue; }
    if(is_dir($file)) { $fileExt = "dir"; }

    /* SORT FILES - First by filename and then by extension */
    $files = glob($handle."/*.*");
    $files = array_map("basename", $files);

    natcasesort($files);

    echo '
<div><a href='.$file.' class='.$fileExt.'>&nbsp;</a></div>
<div><a href='.$file.'>$file</a></div>
';
}

closedir($handle);

?>
```

**Please refer to this posting for more info:**
[PHP - Sort data after original sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509221/php-sort-data-after-original-sort)

Comment: why you passing a handle to `glob` ?

Comment: Please refer to this posting:  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509221/php-sort-data-after-original-sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509221/php-sort-data-after-original-sort) - This will give you insight regarding this issue.  I have also tried " dirname ( _ _ FILE _ _ ) " - no luck.

Comment: @mar2195: this might helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884974/sort-and-display-directory-list-alphabetically-using-opendir-in-php